# Check ContentLength of a large response before downloading content

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm using HttpWebRequest and want to check the ContentLength of the response before the entire response is downloaded. But when calling:

```
var res = request.GetResponse(); // entire response is being downloaded
var len = res.ContentLegth; // need only this value
```

How can this be achived in C# ?

Comment: when you start downloading, you cannot 'pause' that. you can only interrupt the downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the original code in the question actually does work, it only download the "HEAD" when calling "GetResponse" and the ContentLength is avaialble.
It didn't work for me because I was getting a resource that had a "chunked" transfer encoding.
This still should have worked, returning -1 in the ContentLength if I hadn't tested it with fiddler open. Apparantly when fiddler encounters a "chunked" response it tries to download it all, even when just calling "req.GetResponse()".

Comment: Yep. I had the same damn problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a HEAD request, rather than a GET. This will then only return the HTTP headers in the response.

All standardised HTTP request types are documented [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Comment: But you won't get ContentLength

Comment: I just checked and you're right. In which case, the only way I can think of is to read the headers then abort the download after you're received the Content-Length.

Comment: @I4V the content length can be part of the Header based on [This document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Comment: @noobob I wrote this code for you. try it `var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverlow.com");
            req.Method = "HEAD";
            var length = req.GetResponse(); `